# Python newbie here - Index Error: list index out of range

Tags: python, string, indexing

I had a web scraper made that works fine up to the point it sorts the acquired data dumped into e_data. I'm a complete python newbie, and any help would be appreciated.

**The error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\wamp\www\_clients\dstest\web_scrape2.py", line 78, in <module>
customer = row.find_all('td')[2].getText().split()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**The faulty code:**

```
if re.findall('\\bnew\\b', str(e_data)) != []:
for row in e_data.find_all('tr'):
    if re.findall('</table>', str(row)) == [] and re.findall('\\bnew\\b', str(row)) != []:
        job_no = row.find('a').string
        customer = row.find_all('td')[2].getText().split()
        move_date = row.find_all('td')[3].getText()
        result = {'job_no': job_no, 'customer': customer, 'move_date': move_date}
        print json.dumps(result)
else:
print "Data unavailable"
```

**Content of e_data:**

```
<center><b><h3>

Total of: 1 Transactions

<right>
<a href="javascript:window.close()">Exit</a>
<style type="text/css"> .xf{color: blue; text-decoration: underline;} .xn{color: red; text-decoration: underline; cursor: Hand}></style>
</right></h3></b></center>
<table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" width="90%"><tr><td>
<center>
<table bgcolor="#EEEEEE" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" style="font-size: 8pt" width="100">
<tr bgcolor="DarkBlue"><th><font color="White" face="Verdana,Helvetica">job_no</font></th><th><font color="White" face="Verdana,Helvetica">category</font></th><th><font color="White" face="Verdana,Helvetica">customer</font></th><th><font color="White" face="Verdana,Helvetica">move_date</font></th><th><font color="White" face="Verdana,Helvetica">deliver</font></th><th><font color="White" face="Verdana,Helvetica">dlv_imm</font></th><th><font color="White" face="Verdana,Helvetica">origin</font></th><th><font color="White" face="Verdana,Helvetica">destination</font></th><th><font color="White" face="Verdana,Helvetica">miles</font></th><th><font color="White" face="Verdana,Helvetica">cf_lbs</font></th><th><font color="White" face="Verdana,Helvetica">estimate</font></th><th><font color="White" face="Verdana,Helvetica">open_date</font></th><th><font color="White" face="Verdana,Helvetica">vip</font></th></tr><tr style="background:#CCCCFF" valign="TOP"><td><a href="/wc.dll?mprep~printselect~LTPAX57752~UZ2W225186" target="_blank">J4074407</a><br> <b><br><font color="#FF0000">new</font></br></b></br></td></tr></table></center></td></tr></table><td>Long_Dist.<br>FollowUp<br><b><font color="#008000" size="1">REFERENCE</font></b></br></br></td><td><b>Newlead2</b><br>User:SAM       <br>newlead2@gmail.com                                          <br>4838484838</br></br></br></td><td>01/18/2016</td><td>  /  /    <br>  /  /</br></td><td>...</td><td><b>FL FORT LAUDERDALE                                                                                                </b></td><td><b>CA OAKLAND                                  </b></td><td align="RIGHT">3068</td><td>200 cf<br>2000 lbs</br></td><td align="RIGHT">1410.00</td><td align="CENTER">02/18/2015 02:27:05 pm</td><td>...</td>
<tr bgcolor="DarkBlue" style="font-face:bold"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td align="RIGHT"><font color="White"><b>  3068</b></font></td><td></td><td align="RIGHT"><font color="White"><b>   1410.00</b></font></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
```

Comment: Just a guess, but I imagine `row.find_all('td')` doesn't contain 3 items, dunno what format `e_data` is in though so I can't try fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access non-existant element of array from

```
customer = row.find_all('td')[2].getText().split()
```

print the length of array and you'll know

```
len(row.findall('td'))
```

Iterate through all 'td' elements using

```
tdEllements = row.find_all('td')
for tdElement in tdElements:
    #your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first `tr` row does not have any `td`s, so index in out of range when you try to excess `row.find_all('td')[n]`

Try using `try..except` for this:

```
try:
    customer = row.find_all('td')[2].getText().split()
    move_date = row.find_all('td')[3].getText()
except IndexError:
    continue
```